# How To Hide A Facebook Like Box When User Is Not Logged Into Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have added a Facebook like box to a website that because it is a gambling site you must be logged in so it can verify your age and show you content.. which is fine.

My problem is that when a user is not logged into Facebook the like box is still there just without the content, it has an empty background colour.

Is there a way I can hide the containing div around the iframe to display:none using javascript and if so how?

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F(page name)&amp;width=190&amp;height=290&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true&amp;header=false&amp;appId=150863001672601" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="padding:10px; border:1px solid #000000; background:#e1e1e1; overflow:hidden; width:160px; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I Came aross this but Im not sure if this is in the right direction:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{app_id}', // App ID from the App Dashboard
        channelUrl : '//path/to/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
        status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
        cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if ((response.status === 'connected') || (response.status === 'not_authorized'))  {
                $('#facepileDiv').show();
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
(function(d, debug){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, /*debug*/ false));
```

Comment: code?wil b helpful....

Answer (score 0):

Try

**I named the iframe as iframe1**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


 <iframe id="iframe1" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F(page name)&amp;width=190&amp;height=290&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true&amp;header=false&amp;appId=150863001672601" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="padding:10px; border:1px solid #000000; background:#e1e1e1; overflow:hidden; width:160px; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

     <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="btnclk()" />


    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function btnclk() {
        var ifr = document.getElementById("iframe1");
        ifr.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Im not sure why there is a button.. I need to have the like box disappear when the user is not logged into Facebook

Comment: i just added button to show..so here inside the  user is not logged into Facebook condition you can write the button click code to hide it...